# Progress dialog causes application not responding error?

Tags: android

I am showing my upload progress using a `ProgressDialog` in an `AsycTask` but if the upload speed is less and the bar moves taking some time and my application shows application not responding error i.e wait or force close ..bt actually my work is going on and if I choose wait the application runs file..what should I do to remove this application not responding error, or can I increase the time in till so that it doe's show so fast?

in the `doInBackground`  method

```
.
.
.
.
.
.


    int i;          
                    byte[] buf = new byte[512];

                    while ((i = in.read(buf)) != -1) {                  
                        out.write(buf,0,i);
                        publishProgress(in.available());
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
```

and int the progress upgrade method

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
            if(a==0){
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            a++;
            int b=(int) (fil.length()-values[0]);           
            progressDialog.setProgress(b);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason you are getting the ANR is that you are doing your long running task on the UI thread. If you move the blocking stuff onto another thread and notify the UI thread of the progress updates, you might find that the ANR disappears. Apologies if your long running task is already in the background (it is impossible to tell from your code)

You could try using an AsyncTask. This has the notification mechanism built in and manages the threading for you.

Comment: its in the do in backgrond method

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I re-read your post and it makes more sense to me now. I could suggest adding Log comments to the start and end of the onProgressUpdate method to see where your application is when the ANR happens. Alternatively hook up the debugger and see what the stacks look like when the ANR is thrown